# Convert decimal to char postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
select to_char(100.00, 'FM999.0');
```

The result is:

[image]

But if I change it to:

```
select to_char(0, 'FM999.0');
```

I will have:

[image]

It's ugly. How I can get something like: `0` or `0.0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use one `0` before the decimal point:

```
select to_char(0, 'FM990.0');
```